# Pamie and python-win32 question pamie3 not working

Tags: python, winapi, beautifulsoup, pamie

currently im making some web scraping script.
and i was choice PAMIE to use my script.
actually im new to python and programming.
so i have no idea ,if i use PAMIE,it really helpful to make script to relate with win32-python.
ok my problem is ,
while im making script,i was encounter two probelm.
first , i want to let work my script work together Beautifulsoup and PAMIE.
or it also ok..if can work native internet explorer interface together.

but it not work for me.
im using PAMIE3 version.even if i changed to pamie 2b version ,i couldn't make it working.

my second problem is,while im making script,i think sometime i need normal IE interface.
is it possible to change PAMIE's IE interface to just normal IE interface(InternetExplorer.Application)?
i don't want to open new IE window to work with normal IE interface,want to continue work with current PAMIE's IE windows.
sorry for my bad english
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAMIE might be getting a bit dated. You could take a look at Selenium which will also automate a web browser, but is more current.

http://jimmyg.org/blog/2009/getting-started-with-selenium-and-python.html

Comment: hello, actually i was tried selenium.i think selenium can't run standalone. i mean...it should be first run selenium server ,right? and have to can't make EXE file,such like py2exe.after made script i would like to give to my friend. thanks